# how to modify the code to change the size of blocks or nodes with maintaining the symmetry

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, block, size

How I can change the size of nodes to add some text in it. Below is code and second diagram is generated from this code.

```
\begin{figure}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=2.8cm,level distance=2.8cm,
  box/.style={
       shape=rectangle,
       font=\small,
       draw,
       align=center,
       minimum height=1.5cm,
       text width=1.75cm,
       top color=white,
       bottom color=blue!20}
]
\node  [box,text width=3cm] {Indoor\\Localization\\System} [edge from parent fork down]
 child { node [box] {Proximity} }
  child { node [box] {Angulation} 
       child { node [box] {Received Angle} 
             child [sibling distance=2.2cm] { node [box] {AOA}
            child [sibling distance=2.2cm] { node [box] {Antenna array} }}}}
  child { node [box] {Scene Analysis} }
  child [sibling distance=3cm] { node [box] (lat) {Lateration}
        child [sibling distance=4.5cm]  { node [box] {Propagation time}
             child [sibling distance=2.2cm] { node [box] {TOA}
                        child [sibling distance=2.2cm] { node [box] {RF or ultrasonic} }}
             child [sibling distance=2.2cm] { node [box] {TDOA}
                        child [sibling distance=2.2cm] { node [box] {RF or Ultrasonic} }} }
        child [sibling distance=3.4cm]{ node [box] (tof) {Signal Strength}
                child [sibling distance=2.2cm] { node [box] {RSS} 
                 child [sibling distance=2.2cm] { node [box] {RF} }}} };


\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Overview of Localization}
\end{figure}
```

[image][image]

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{}` should only be used in the preamble of your document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code I can't reproduce your image. It looks fine. Anyway, I slightly reduce your code and select new sibling distances. With this changes I obtain the following picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=2.8cm,level distance=2.8cm,
  box/.style={
       shape=rectangle,
       font=\small,
       draw,
       align=center,
       minimum height=1.3cm,
       text width=1.75cm,
       top color=white,
       bottom color=blue!20},
level 1/.style = {sibling distance=2.6cm},
level 2/.style = {sibling distance=3.4cm},
level 3/.style = {sibling distance=2.4cm},
                        ]
\node  [box,text width=3cm] {Indoor\\Localization\\System} [edge from parent fork down]
 child { node [box] {Proximity} }
  child { node [box] {Angulation}
       child { node [box] {Received Angle}
            child { node [box] {AOA}%sibling distance=2.2cm
            child  { node [box] {Antenna array} }}}}%[sibling distance=2.2cm]
  child { node [box] {Scene Analysis} }
  child  { node [box] (lat) {Lateration}%[sibling distance=3cm]
        child   { node [box] {Propagation time}%[sibling distance=4.5cm]
             child  { node [box] {TOA}%[sibling distance=2.2cm]
                        child  { node [box] {RF or ultrasonic} }}%[sibling distance=2.2cm]
             child [sibling distance=2.2cm] { node [box] {TDOA}
                        child  { node [box] {RF or Ultrasonic} }} }%[sibling distance=2.2cm]
        child { node [box] (tof) {Signal Strength}%[sibling distance=3.4cm]
                child  { node [box] {RSS}%[sibling distance=2.2cm]
                 child  { node [box] {RF} }}} };%[sibling distance=2.2cm]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In code I comment all your sibling distances and instead of them define them with `level`styles.

Answer (score 2):

This answer demonstrates two things:

1. that a **forest** solution obviates the need to specify sibling distances manually - the tree is automatically packed to create a compact and concise form;
2. that the experimental package **justtrees** can be used to add the labels shown on the right of the original diagram and **forest** can automatically add the arrows.

I don't know if you have any interest in the labels as you didn't mention it but I need test cases, so might as well inflict the results on the unwary while I'm at it.

Should you wish to try this at home, let me know that you would like a copy as it is not yet readily available (i.e. not on CTAN).

Here's the result so you can decide whether to bother reading further. I don't know if the topmost arrow should align with the other arrows or with the node at which it points. I went with the latter, but the former just needs a slight modification.

[image: aligned things with arrows and labels]

The big advantage of **forest** is the power and flexibility it provides when drawing trees, especially the potential for automation and consistent formatting. It also draws very compact trees by default.

**justtrees** is a **forest** wrapper designed to do one thing: automatically align labels at the left or right of the tree, allowing the label content to be specified as part of the tree and providing a couple of keys to customise the labels' format.

## Preamble

Load the code:

```
\usepackage{justtrees}% v 0.07
```

For the arrow tips:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
```

We'll use the `edges` library as it allows us to easily get the equivalent of `edge from parent fork down`.

```
\useforestlibrary{edges}
```

Apply the `edges` settings as default. Do this within a local TeX scope if you don't want it to apply to every `forest` tree in the document.

```
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{edges}
```

## Body

**justtrees** provides a new environment `justtree` which takes a single mandatory argument which should provide the tree's preamble. This may be empty, but the argument cannot be omitted.

```
\begin{justtree}
  {
```

To get the squared turns in the edges.

```
    forked edges,
```

We want some things applied to every node in the tree. This is essentially your style `box` modified very slightly for compatibility.

```
    for tree={
      font=\small,
      draw,
```

Rather than `align=center`, we need this. (I'm not sure why, though.)

```
      text centered,
      minimum height=1.5cm,
      text width=1.75cm,
```

We need this to keep things aligned.

```
      anchor=north,
      top color=white,
      bottom color=blue!20,
```

If we want sans text. Otherwise, omit.

```
      font=\sffamily,
    },
```

This is the format of the labels on the right. We shift them right to allow room for the arrows.

```
    just format={xshift=25pt, font=\sffamily},
```

This code is responsible for drawing the arrows. We delay it to make sure that the locations of all nodes in the main tree have been calculated so that our arrows do not end up in unexpected places.

```
    before drawing tree={
```

This is a bit complicated. It works, but I'm not certain whether it is right. The manual needs to provide simpler examples (or just some examples at all) for idiots like me ;)!

This walks from node to node and does something at each step. `r` is the root of the tree. `L` is the last leaf i.e. the bottom right node. `current and ancestors` then moves back up from the last leaf to the root i.e. right-bottom-node -> parent -> grandparent -> great-grandparent -> ... -> root.

```
      for nodewalk={rL,current and ancestors}{
```

We don't want an arrow for levels `0` or `1` of our tree. (Level `0` is actually invisible when using a `justtree`.) So we test the current level at each step, do nothing if it is less than 2 and otherwise draw our arrow, aligning it with the appropriate anchor to align with the labels which will end up on the right and the current node.

```
        if={level()<2}{}{tikz+={\draw [Stealth-] (.mid east) ++(2.5pt,0) -- ++(15pt,0);},},
      },
    },
  }
```

That's the preamble. Now the tree in **forest**'s bracket notation. Note that we can add regular TikZ options to nodes and **forest** will pass them on.

```
  [Indoor\\Localization\\System, text width=3cm
```

The label on the right is specified using `just=<label content>`. It just needs to be passed to a node on the right level - it doesn't matter which one.

```
  [Proximity, just={Positioning}
    ]
    [Angulation
      [Received\\Angle
        [AOA
          [Antenna\\array
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Scene\\Analysis
    ]
    [Lateration
```

A couple more labels.

```
      [Propagation\\time, just=Variable
        [TOA
          [RF or\\ultrasonic, just=Device
          ]
        ]
        [TDOA
          [RF or\\Ultrasonic
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Signal\\Strength
```

Final label. These are dispersed within the tree just to show it doesn't matter where they are specified.

```
        [RSS, just=Ranging
          [RF
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Close the environment and we're done.

```
\end{justtree}
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{justtrees}% v 0.07
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{edges}
\begin{document}
\begin{justtree}
  {
    forked edges,
    for tree={
      font=\small,
      draw,
      text centered,
      minimum height=1.5cm,
      text width=1.75cm,
      anchor=north,
      top color=white,
      bottom color=blue!20,
      font=\sffamily,
    },
    just format={xshift=25pt, font=\sffamily},
    before drawing tree={
      for nodewalk={rL,current and ancestors}{
        if={level()<2}{}{tikz+={\draw [Stealth-] (.mid east) ++(2.5pt,0) -- ++(15pt,0);},},
      },
    },
  }
  [Indoor\\Localization\\System, text width=3cm
  [Proximity, just={Positioning}
    ]
    [Angulation
      [Received\\Angle
        [AOA
          [Antenna\\array
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Scene\\Analysis
    ]
    [Lateration
      [Propagation\\time, just=Variable
        [TOA
          [RF or\\ultrasonic, just=Device
          ]
        ]
        [TDOA
          [RF or\\Ultrasonic
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Signal\\Strength
        [RSS, just=Ranging
          [RF
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{justtree}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) :-). Is it possible to adjust `just=...` to center of node? Now seems to be aligned with first line of text in node. If I moved `just=Device` to RF node, I obtain nicer result.

Comment: It's because I aligned them to the baseline of text. Usually this is better. You can override it with `just format` I *think*. I'll look later.

Comment: Probably the best solution is to just move it to the node, as you suggest. It isn't easy to find settings for `just format` which look good for all levels of the tree. Maybe with **prooftrees** which is a bit more sophisticated, but that is also much less flexible and would likely not work at all well for this in general. I'd either rewrite or extend **justtrees** or manually hack something into working for the occasional nodes/trees needing something different, I think.